# Responsive dropdown CSS fix

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design

Here is Fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/fpCpc/`"> jsfiddle

Issue is when I scroll down on dropdown navigation Top part doesn't stay Active - I also took the screenshot to make it clear!  [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/tw8mfddkt/)

Please any hint will be help full! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this block of styles:

```
.dd_menu_wrapper a:hover,
.dd_menu_wrapper label:hover {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#eff0f1;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

You need to add:

```
.dd_parent:hover label
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpCpc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.dd_parent:hover > label {
    color:#000;
}
```

DEMO [**jsFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/fpCpc/2/)